# GetService throws an error: "Could not find a part of the path 'E:\TFSWorkItemTrackingCache\v11"

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to return the `WorkItemStore` from a `TfsTeamProjectCollection` instance.

The code is straight forward:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(this.Path), new NetworkCredential(this.UserName, pwd, this.Domain));

tfs.Authenticate();

WorkItemStore store = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
```

but that line errors out when calling GetService. The error passed back reads:

> "Could not find a part of the path 'E:\TFSWorkItemTrackingCache\v11"

There is no such path on the server where the TFS instance resides, and even adding the folder makes no difference.

What is going on here and how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Have you [cleared your the TFS Cache](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/08/19/how-to-clear-visual-studio-team-explorer-cache.aspx) on that Machine?

Comment: I found a cache folder on the server but it doesn't look as simple to clear it as the recommendation in the link you provided. The instructions are for 2010 and we are running 2012. I'm also not seeing a way to clear the cache from the administration console. Is there a safe way to do this?

Comment: I did try clearing the cache on my local computer which made no difference.

Comment: I did find a proxy configuration file that points to D:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Version Control Proxy\_tfs_data for the cache on the server, but that folder is empty. I can't find any configuration file that points to E:\TFSWorkItemTrackingCache\v11

Comment: Is there a TFS Proxy Server configured anywhere?

Comment: When I click on the Proxy Server item in the administration console the url points to the same server with a different port, and the cache root directory is listed as D:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Version Control Proxy\_tfs_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Someone added this to the web.config
add key="WorkItemTrackingCacheRoot" value="E:\TFSWorkItemTrackingCache"